# Are there widgets available for promoting Ubuntu on your site?

Tags: community

I currently have the Maverick countdown widget on my site and was wondering if there are any widgets available now that it's fully released with which to replace it.

Comment: This question is under [discussion on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/584/1273).

Comment: Hi @Chris. I've reverted this question back to how you originally asked it. Questions on Ask Ubuntu work better when they are, well exactly that, questions that can be answered. Thank you for asking though, it's a good question in my opinion :) (You may like to look at our discussion [on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/584/do-we-promote-collection-wikis) and [in chat](http://chat.askubuntu.com/transcript/message/9846#9846) about this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spreadubuntu.org](http://spreadubuntu.org/en) is designed as a one-stop-shot for Ubuntu promotional material.

Answer (score 3):

There are some attleast at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WebsiteButtons, tho those are not as fancy as countdown banner were. Maybe someone else knows more?

Answer (score 3):

What you might be able to do is use the official branding found at this link:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Brand

And then tweak it so that when the user clicks on it, it sends them to ubuntu.com or the desired website.

Answer (score 2):

There are some generic site buttons on http://spreadubuntu.neomenlo.org/
Probably will not be long before someone makes some Maverick related ones.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [42-based widget](http://design.canonical.com/wp-content/themes/canonical-design/42day/) from the Design Team.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu Brand Guidelines http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/ubuntu-brand-guidelines/ has an archive http://design.canonical.com/brand/Logos/Ubuntu_brandmark_aw.zip with images with the ubuntu logo (svg, png, eps) for print and web, in different colors and positions.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the countdown widget turns into a static pomotional widget once the countdown ends. That was exactly what I was looking for.